# Label :hover attribute triggers incorrect element in IE10 and IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

This is a little weird, but bear with me.  This only affects IE10 and IE11, doesn't affect Chrome, FF, Safari, and IE9 and older.  If you have a `<label>` for another element nested within a class that the `:hover` is assigned to, it will match that selector, even if you are not hovering over that element.  In the example below, if you hover over the first `div`, both `divs` are highlighted.

```
<div>
    <select id="min-price">
        <option>A</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div>
    <label for="min-price"></label>
    <select>            
        <option>B</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

and this CSS:

```
div {
    padding: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

div:hover {
    background: #f1f1f1;
}

div:hover > select {
    background-color: #a3a3a3;
}
```

Example can be found here.

http://jsfiddle.net/0c67oew2/3/

Any anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: This isn't an issue in IE9, it only is an issue in ie10 and above.

Comment: What `DOCTYPE` are you using?

Comment: It's in the fiddle.  `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: It's a really weird behavior, but think this way. When you hover the `div`, at some point it also hovers the `select` child element, which by design will reflect into its `label`. It looks like on `IE` it causes this _bug_. If you hover the second `div` this doesn't happen.

Comment: @MelanciaUK, I'm leaning towards this being a design flaw in the IE10+ rendering engine. CSS parses from right to left. The engine matches on .price, then moves left to the next selector, finds :hover, (without checking the class) and it matches, moves to the next selector .control and matches

Comment: Yes, I got what you mean. It's definitely something wrong with `IE10+`. And on `IE9-` `:hover` had other problems.

Comment: The intrinsic relationship between labels and their associated elements is *bi-directional* in Internet Explorer. If you hover an element, you hover its ancestral tree too. So when you hover a select element, you hover its ancestral tree, any associated label, and that labels ancestral tree. I don't yet know if this is a *bug* in IE, or IE going the extra mile in making the relationship bi-directional.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to note before you read this answer that I am an engineer on the Internet Explorer team.

First of all, this is a *really* cool discovery. What you've stumbled upon is actually a "feature" (quite possibly a bug) of Internet Explorer that doesn't appear to exist in Chrome or Firefox. Let me try to break down an understanding of what is happening, why this is kind of cool, and what you can do to avoid complications with it:

Labels and input elements can become intrinsically related by way of the `[for]` attribute on a `label` pointing to the `[id]` attribute on an `input` element. As a result, when you click on a label, it can toggle a checkbox, or apply focus to an input field. This feature is often times leveraged to create progressively-enhanced radio buttons and more.

On a related note, when you *hover* over a `label`, the associated `input` element is also hovered. This is the case with Internet Explorer, Firefox, Chrome, and just about everybody else. But what Internet Explorer does differently is apply the hover bi-directional. So if you hover the associated `input` control, Internet Explorer *also* invokes `:hover` on the related `label`.

[This is where things get cool](http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/a9uqzd0g/3/). This allows us to create relationships like the one seen below:

[image]

Note here that the relationship is bi-directional, meaning any hover on an `input` is not simply a hover on itself and its ancestral tree, but also a hover on its associated `label`. And any hover on a `label` is a hover on itself, its ancestral tree, and its associated `input`. This brings us one step closer to understanding what's at play in your demo, and why you're seeing such bizarre results.

When you hover an element, you are covering *its parents* too. As an example, suppose we had a `div` with a `button` inside of it. Any hover on the `button` is inherently a hover on the parent `div` as well. You can't get to the children without first going through the parents as far as a cursor is concerned. The same rule applies here; when a label or input is hovered, so too are its parents.

In your demo you have a series of `div` elements with `select` elements and `label` elements inside. You're basing styles for the `select` elements on the hover pseudo-class of their parent `div`. So when you hover the `select`, it invokes the hover of its associated `label`, which causes the hover of its parent, which affects the styles of any nested `select`.

*Subsequent Suggestion*

While the `[for]` attribute allows you to place `label` elements just about anywhere, you should proceed in doing so only with special awareness to how this will affect selectors operating off of `:hover` propagation up the ancestral tree.

Before a complete solution can be given, I must ask why you are putting an empty label in a seemingly arbitrary location in the first place. What visual effect are you trying to achieve? I suspect we could accomplish the same visual layout with different markup.

*Following Up from Here*

I'm going to open a bug against this in our Internal database, because I get the feeling that this isn't entirely intentional on our part. Our aim, I believe, is to treat the behavior the same bi-directionally, rather than handling the two routes differently.

Comment: "So when you hover the select, it invokes the hover of its associated label, which causes the hover of its parent, which affects the styles of any nested select." This is why devs are frustrated with Internet Explorer in general. Cory only wanted a hover effect on the select box.

Comment: @edendramis I sincerely fail to see how this is reason to be frustrated with the browser. *All* major browsers propagate `:hover` up the subjects ancestral tree. *All* major browsers create an intrinsic relationship between a `label` and its *associated element* (per the spec). IE appears to be the only major browser to respect that intrinsic relationship bi-directionally. This is certainly not interoperable, and worth an investigation on our side, but I don't think this is reason to be frustrated with the browser.

Comment: @JonathanSampson Thanks for you awesome reply.  I appreciate you adding this to your internal ticket tracker.  Is it possible to view the progress of this ticket?  I'm not sure I'd agreed with your statement a hover on a "button is inherently a hover on the parent div as well",  we have `pointer-events` for that reason alone.  The example is contrived to isolate the behavior.  You could have the same effect, if you used labels within a `fieldset` and set the `:hover` on the `fieldset`.

Comment: @Cory It's a matter of containers; you cannot put your mouse over a child without first putting it over the parent. `pointer-events` allows us to prevent the default behavior, instead allowing pass-through events among other things.

Comment: @JonathanSampson Thanks for taking the time to respond to this question.  I've updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/0c67oew2/7/ to include a `pointer-events` example. The 2nd div parent in this case shouldn't allow events to bubble up.  Yet the result is the same, if you hover over the first select, you'll see both fields being highlighted.

Comment: @Cory Your use of `pointer-events` definitely suggests more to this bug than earlier demos show. I'll include this as part of the ticket I file against this issue.

Comment: @JonathanSampson  That's awesome, thanks.  Is there anywhere I can track the progress of the ticket?

Comment: @Cory I can create the ticket through http://connect.microsoft.com, but if you want granular updates on the issue please feel free to ping me occasionally and I can relay those to you. Meanwhile, I'd love to help you find a work-around; what is the reason for putting the `label` in the second `div`?

Comment: "This is certainly not interoperable"

To me, that is *the* reason to be frustrated with the browser. It's creating yet another special case to account for.

Comment: @DerekPeterson My point was that the behavior is logical, and makes sense once you understand what it is doing. Special cases exist in all browsers. However, they don't always make sense. In this case, the issue makes perfect sense - that's all I'm stating.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using :focus instead of :hover when dealing with form inputs. One reason for this is because if a user tabs through using a keyboard, the hover won't do anything, but a focus will.

```
.control .price:focus {
  background: #a3a3a3;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the accessibility tip, but :focus won't get the job done.  I need the element to have some form of user feedback on hover.

Comment: Upon further review, I guess I don't understand what the issue is. I'm getting the same results in Chrome and IE, and they are working as intended based on the CSS you've written. What exactly is the desired result?

Comment: Try IE10 or IE11.  Click the jsfiddle link above.  Hover over the `<select>`, it shouldn't highlight the second `<div>` or `<select>`

Comment: Ok, I see now...and the problem is how you're using the label and not the label tag itself. If you change the name of the label, you will see that it works. The label and input of the shared name should probably be in the same container.

Comment: @slime is right - the label is throwing off the immediate child relationship (>) from your css.  I did a fiddle with labels 'for' the other div's select, and the same issue now happens when "B" is hovered http://jsfiddle.net/jzbbcbt7/.  Removing or revising the label will fix your issue.

Comment: <label> can, and should, be able to exist anywhere in the DOM. I'm leaning towards this being a design flaw in the IE10+ rendering engine. CSS parses from right to left. The engine matches on .price, then moves left to the next selector, finds :hover, (without checking the class) and it matches, moves to the next selector .control and matches

Comment: It's not a one way issue as described either. If you place text inside the label you will see it highlights the select on top, the reversal of your problem, but this tells me that the browser is tracking hovers and not just click, which I thought was the default  behavior and Chrome shows this too, but I think you're right in saying that IE doesn't know how to handle a situation like this. But I've never see a situation like this either. Why is your label next to a select it's not assigned to anyways?

Comment: Also, looks like IE applies its own styling to selects when the label is hovered or vice-versa, which is what you're actually seeing. Perhaps try resetting the style for IE?