# input:hover+label override important styles [only IE11 bug]

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

Look at the code: 
color: red!important; doesn't work in IE11 [Windows 10].
In all another brauser it looks fine, how it should be, please check.

```css
input:hover+label {
    color: green;
}
label:hover {
    color: red!important;
}
```

```html
 <input placeholder="What do your friends call you?" id="fname" />
 <label for="fname">First Name</label>
```

Comment: Seems this is another "feature" of IE. This answer seems to be related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27555724/3244925

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I saw that answer, but he didn't give a hint how to avoid it. I'm just interesting is it possible somehow to fix.

Comment: Sampson was leaning towards that feature being a bug.  Since it's low priority, it'll likely never be fixed.  If possible, just make the selector more specific. e.g. target an ID